# Conversion to pinescript v4

Tags: global-variables, pine-script

I am trying to convert the following function into pinescript v4.0:

```
ssFilter( price, lowerBand ) =>
    angle = sqrt(2)*PI/lowerBand
    a1= exp(-angle)
    b1 = 2*a1*cos(angle)
    c2 = b1
    c3 = -a1*a1
    c1 = 1 - c2 -c3
    filt := c1*(price + nz(price[1]))/2 + c2*nz(filt[1]) + c3*nz(filt[2])
```

But, it returns with an error:

> Cannot modify global variable 'filt' in function

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be like this

```
ssFilter(price, lowerBand) =>
    angle = sqrt(2)*PI/lowerBand
    a1= exp(-angle)
    b1 = 2*a1*cos(angle)
    c2 = b1
    c3 = -a1*a1
    c1 = 1 - c2 -c3
    c1*(price + nz(price[1]))/2 + c2*nz(filt[1]) + c3*nz(filt[2])
```

and then in your main code, you should use your function to assign the result to `filt`, like this:

```
filt := ssFilter(price, lowerBand)
```

Comment: Thanks for simple solution.....It worked for me.......Appreciated.